# Is it Possible to create two separate Identity tables for Storing Separate Login information in Asp .Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, model-associations

I am a beginner in Asp.net MVC framework.

Can Asp.net MVC 5 
allows to create two separate identity tables which has independent columns for storing two different user information including username and password.

Store schema as follows

```
Stores table
  id
  storename
  address
  ....
```

As per the requirement the I have two different types of Users namely RetailUsers and Suppliers.

1) A RetailUser should be assigned to only one Store and the table schema is as follows

```
RetailUsers table
  id
  username
  password
  name
  address
  StoreId
```

So, there will be one Store assigned to a RetailUser.

2) A Supplier will be assigned to multiple Stores and the table schema is as follows

```
Suppliers table
  id
  username
  password
  suppliername
  address
  payment
  ....

SupplierStores table
  SupplierId
  StoreId
```

So, there will be multiple Stores assigned to multiple Suppliers.

**Association of RetailUser and Supplier model with Store Model**

```
RetailUser model belongs to Store model

Suppliers model has many Stores model
```

As per the requirement RetailUsers and Suppliers to have two different logins. So, we thought to have two different identity tables.
Please help me on how to create two separate identity tables for RetailUsers and Suppliers with the above mentioned fields.

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you add some details about the reasons for you wanting to do this.  Explain your overall goal a little bit more clearly in terms of architecture.

Comment: I have updated the question... is it enough?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "Yes, you can". But it is a lot of work. Since your question does not contain enough details and reasons behind this question, I recommend not to do this.
Especially given the "beginner in Asp.net MVC" - do the most simple thing first.

**Update**
No need to create separate tables for users. Have a table with users. Then tables for `RetailUserInfo` and for `SuppliersInfo`. Then link back from both of these tables to users-table.

This way you separate concerns - information about logins is stored in one table, info about Suppliers in another, info about customers in third.

No need to hack Identity into pieces.

Comment: I have updated the Question with my usecase.. can you tell me how it could be achieved

Comment: how will you map Stores table with RetailUsers table

Comment: I would not have `RetailUsers` table. I'd have `Users`, then `CustomersInfo` that links to `Stores`. Basically change the way your depedency goes.

Comment: RetailUsers and Suppliers has different relationships with Stores. For example:  ````RetailUser Model belongs to Store```` and ````Supplier Model has many Stores```` through SupplierStores  intermediate table

Comment: Yes, whatever the structure you have, it can be modelled that `IdentityUsers` table does not depend on anything, and have `RetailUsers` and `SupplierUsers` point to it.

Comment: @Trailmax is offering good advice.  In my opinion your model starts to get out-of-whack when you begin overlapping Supplier and User concepts.  If you switch the way you are thinking about the concept of _SupplierUser_ vs. _RetailUser_ into the idea of _User (with ROLE Supplier)_ vs. _User (with ROLE Retail)_ I think it will start to become more clear.  You can deal with your 'different relationships' to *Stores* by giving your _Users_ table two relational columns (both optional): one with `StoreId` required for Retail role users, and another with `SupplierId` for Supplier role users.